# How can I correctly pass arguments to a C++ function from C# using PInvoke?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, pinvoke, marshalling

I have a *C++* dll with the following method signature:

```
int create_Entry(void* deal_key, void* trade_data);
```

I have been told that ***deal_key*** can be a *String* e.g. `SOME-ID` and ***trade_data*** is a struct with the following structure:

```
struct TradeData 
{
    const char* product_id;
    double notional;
    int trade_date;
    int trade_settlement_date;
};
```

I then try calling the function using the following in *C#*:

```
[DllImport("My.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "create_Entry")]
private static extern int CreateEntry(string deal_key, MyTradeData trade_data);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Auto, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
struct MyTradeData
{
    public string product_id;
    public double notional;
    public int trade_date;
    public int trade_settlement_date;
}

var tradeData = new MyTradeData
{
    product_id = "SOME-ID",
    notional = 1000000.0,
    trade_date = 43971,
    trade_settlement_date = 43972
};

CreateEntry("SOME-ID", tradeData);
```

But I get the following error:

> Cannot marshal 'parameter #2': Invalid managed/unmanaged type
>   combination.

*[Disclaimer]*
I am a newbie when it comes to *PInvoke*, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The DLLImport requires object to be in unmanaged memory space while c# objects are in managed memory.  So you need to take your struct and use Marshal.StructureToPtr to get an unmanaged pointer.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.structuretoptr?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: You also want to use `LayoutKind.Sequential` and not `LayoutKind.Auto`. Also use `CharSet.Ansi` not `CharSet.Auto` or `CharSet.Unicode`.

Comment: What @jdweng says is not true. The marshaler is capable of marshaling such a struct. The main issue you have here are the character sets and also the fact that you pass the struct by value but it needs to go by reference.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, Thanks! That fixed it.

Comment: You might want to add the `[In]` attribute on the second arg which will stop the marshaler wasting time marshaling the interop struct back into the managed object.